# looping over strings to change working directory

Tags: string, loops, directory

I have a vector/list of countries that I want to use to loop over command to change directory:

```
countries
countries
1     india
2       usa
i<-1
setwd("/Users/AS/Desktop/R/countries[i,]")
```

I was testing if this would open directory for India, but nothing. I also tried by making a list:

```
>countries<-c("india" "usa")
for (i in countries) {
setwd("/Users/Amit/Desktop/R Tahsin/i")
}
```

Neither work, any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike SAS and Stata, R really isn't a macro language. You can use `paste0` for your purpose.

```
# The root directory
rootdir <- "/Users/Amit/Desktop/R Tahsin/"

# Vector of directories (contained within rootdir) to loop over
countries <- c("india","usa")

# Number of countries
n <- length(countries)

# Loop through the directories
for(i in 1:n) {
   setwd(paste0(rootdir,countries[i])) # paste0(rootdir,countries[i]) is equivalent to paste(rootdir,countries[i],sep="")
   # do things...
}
```